# time series analysis using python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to the python. Can any one help me, how to plot the station data (y-axis: column 4) with the corresponding times(x-axis: columns 3). I now how to read the data in python but i dont know how to plot with the corresponding timestamps.

Andhra_Pradesh 14.7 77.7 2013-12-31:01 013
Andhra_Pradesh 14.7 77.7 2013-12-31:02 013
Andhra_Pradesh 14.7 77.7 2013-12-31:03 013
Andhra_Pradesh 14.7 77.7 2013-12-31:04 013
Andhra_Pradesh 14.7 77.7 2013-12-31:05 014
Andhra_Pradesh 14.7 77.7 2013-12-31:06 014

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

f = open('anantpur_2010-13.txt','r')  
for line in f:  
    columns = line.split()  
    line = line.strip()  
    values = columns[4]  
    date = columns[3]  
f.close()
```

Comment: There are many resources available online to show you how to plot a simple chart using Python.

Answer (score 0):

See the [date demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) on on the matplotlib website.